# How do asset links in wordpress page get built? I get http rather that https after moving to docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm suppsed to move to docker (docker-compose) a wordpress site that already works "correctly" in cPanel. I say "correctly" as the "site url" and "wordpress site url" both report `http://` rather that `https`.

In the cPanel setup you can visit `http` or `https` and any internal link to `js` and `css` use `https`. After moving to docker behind `traefik` load balancer I get the page with all links using `http`. That clearly breaks security and the site is unusable.

What's the mechanism used to build up the links to assets? does it use some variables that can be set differently? My docker has apache and I'm using the same .htaccess (at least I'm using what is in the cPanel's backup...).

If I force to `https`, `/wp-admin` becomes unreachable... Currently traefik serves correclty resources requested using both `http` and `https`.

EDIT: adding

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

*does* turn most internal links to https, but `/wp-admin`  becomes unreachable ("you're not allowed to visit thie page"). As an example it loads `/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js` via http.

Why the
Any hint is appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it rearranging the order of the settings in `wp-config.php`.

`wp-configi.php` is not just a configuration file as the name suggests. You need to set `_SERVER['HTTP']` before the last line:

```
$_SERVER["HTTPS"] = "on";
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

(thanks to my friend Dario for the help).

Answer (score 0):

I use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for tunnelling to my `localhost`, and the only way I could successfully run my environment over proxied `https` is by converting wordpress permalink url's to relative urls using...

https://wordpress.org/plugins/relative-url/

The plugin is 2 years out of date but still does the job fine and allows my tunnelling to my `localhost` to run over `https`. Handy for `localhost` `https` endpoint access (without force define home/urls in wp-config.php)

Comment: But the current code, w/o need of any plugin correctly works in the cPanel. I don't simply want to solve this. I want to understand what's the difference between the 2 environments. Same code, Same db => must be some header passed byt the proxy.